# Manhattan distance between any two blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a $m \times n$ matrix. In which few places are placed by number $1$ and other by number $0$.

Now let $d$ be the Manhattan distance between any two blocks containing the number $1$.

Now we have to find total number of unordered pair for each $d$.

I want to know what could be the **shortest method** for it.

example:

$m$ and $n$ are $3$ and $4$ respectively

matrix is

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The value of $d \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

For each value of $d$, number of pairs would be:

$d(1)=1$

$d(2)=0$

$d(3)=1$

$d(4)=1$

$d(5)=0$